# Connect to MS SQL server on a virtual machine from XAMPP localhost on Mac and Virtual Machine

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, xampp, vmware-fusion

I want to use php installed on a Mac to connect to MS SQL server on a virtual machine on the same Mac.

What do I need to do to enable php to accomplish this?
What do I need to do on the Virtual Machine to allow this?

Comment: the you just have to the ms server to allow what ever ip with the correct credentials to correct?

Comment: Which version and edition of SQL Server and virtual Windows OS? What client library are you using in PHP to connect? What errors or other specific problem do you have?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 R2
XAMPP PHP
ERROR: Unable to connect to server

Comment: XAMPP is an application server distribution, not a SQL Server client library. But it looks like it includes FreeTDS so have you searched this site for questions about connecting to SQL Server using FreeTDS? Of course, your code may be using some other client library, if so then you need to clearly identify which one the PHP code is using. And the SQL Server instance needs to be accessible from the Mac, i.e. it should have TCP/IP enabled.